# How to extract text before "br"?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have small question. I am using python 2.7.8. I am trying to extract text which should be before <**br**>. I have like:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="entry-content" >
<p>Here is a listing of C interview questions on “Variable Names” along with answers, explanations and/or solutions:
</p>

<p>1. C99 standard guarantees uniqueness of ____ characters for internal names.<br>
a) 31<br>
b) 63<br>
c) 12<br>
d) 14</p>
<p> more </p>
<p>2. C99 standard guarantess uniqueness of _____ characters for external names.<br>
a) 31<br>
b) 6<br>
c) 12<br>
d) 14</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code which i have tries is currently getting after <**br**> not before br.Here is the code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(htmls)

for br2 in soup2.findAll('br'):
    next = br2.previousSibling
    if not (next and isinstance(next,NavigableString)):
        continue
    next2 = next.previousSibling
    if next2 and isinstance(next2,Tag) and next2.name == 'br':
        text = str(next).strip()
        if text:

            print "Found:", next.encode('utf-8')
```

and the output is giving me:

```
Found: 
a) 31
Found: 
b) 63
Found: 
c) 12
Found:
d) 14 
a) 31
Found: 
b) 6
Found: 
c) 12
Found:
d) 14 
Found:
```

Any idea where i am doing wrong.

Comment: any one ???  i am still trying but fail...

Comment: well list is not inside. if u can just express how u saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would switch to [`BeautifulSoup` version 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead. BeautifulSoup3 is very old and is not maintained anymore:

> Beautiful Soup 3 has been replaced by Beautiful Soup 4.
>
> Beautiful Soup 3 only works on Python 2.x, but Beautiful Soup 4 also
>   works on Python 3.x. Beautiful Soup 4 is faster, has more features,
>   and works with third-party parsers like lxml and html5lib. Once the
>   beta period is over, you should use Beautiful Soup 4 for all new
>   projects.

Run:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

And change your import statement from:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

---

Now, what I would do here is to locate the question text and [get the following `br` siblings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling). For every sibling, get the `next_sibling` which would be the answer option. Working code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")  # using "html5lib" parser here

for question in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"^\d+\.")):
    answers = [br.next_sibling.strip() for br in question.find_next_siblings("br")]

    print(question)
    print(answers)
    print("------")
```

For the sample HTML provided in the question, it prints:

```
1. C99 standard guarantees uniqueness of ____ characters for internal names.
[u'a) 31', u'b) 63', u'c) 12', u'd) 14']
------
2. C99 standard guarantess uniqueness of _____ characters for external names.
[u'a) 31', u'b) 6', u'c) 12', u'd) 14']
------
```

Note that you might need to install [`html5lib` library](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python):

```
pip install html5lib
```

Comment: i am on python 2.7.8. Does html5lib and b4 support this?

Comment: i got this error: eatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: i have installed  b4 and html5

Comment: @user3440716 okay, this means that you have not installed `html5lib`: run `pip install html5lib`.

Comment: i installed but i made change "soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls, "lxml") " so it is also as alternative answer :) and is working

Comment: @user3440716 yeah, `lxml` parser is also handling the case. `html.parser` though would not work here.